# XML endTag Line Break

Tags: android, xml, line, break

I am trying to create an XML document from Android, and I'm facing some problems. Here is some of my code:

```
XmlSerializer xml = Xml.newSerializer();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(); xml.setOutput(writer);
xml.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
xml.startTag("" , "EDbAuditoria");
xml.startTag("", "AFSeq");  xml.text(this.getAFSeq()); xml.endTag("", "AFSeq");
xml.startTag("", "Data");   xml.text(this.getData());  xml.endTag("", "Data");
```

This works fine and generates the file, but when checking the file .. there are no line breaks between tags .. Here follows some lines of the generated file:

No Line Breaks between Tags

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?><EDbAuditoria><AFSeq>LIPO20130709204106R43540</AFSeq><Data>09/07/2013</Data>
```

It should be created as ...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<EDbAuditoria>
<AFSeq>98184ESTAGIARIO22013020502:4423307</AFSeq>
<Data>05/02/2013</Data>
<Hora>02:44 pm</Hora>
<Auditor>ESTAGIARIO2</Auditor>
<Shopping>027</Shopping>
<Loja>108</Loja>
<Qtd>2</Qtd>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my code I use

```
xml.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
```

after `startDocument`. That should give you:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<EDbAuditoria>
    <AFSeq>98184ESTAGIARIO22013020502:4423307</AFSeq>
    <Data>05/02/2013</Data>
    <Hora>02:44 pm</Hora>
    ...
```

Currently I cannot find it in the [documentation](http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output), only [example](http://www.robin-walter.de/home/blog/android-xml-datei-erstellen-und-auf-sd-karte-speichern) [code](http://www.idevlife.com/112024/). But for me it works.

Answer (score 0):

Line breaks and other whitespace aren't necessarily insignificant in any random XML vocabulary. If you want automatic indentation, you have to explicitly tell the serializer to add it.

xml.setOutputFormat(new OutputFormat("XML", "UTF-8", true));